# How many arrangements for students and teachers

Tags: combinatorics

> Let $60$ students and $10$ teachers. How many arrangements are there, such that, between two teachers must be exactly $6$ students?

I know that there are $10!$ permutations for the teachers, and there are $54$ places between them for the students. Nothing said about the edges. Hence, at the edges might be $0-6$ students.

I've been told the answer is $10!\cdot 60!\cdot 7$ but I'm not sure why..I'll be glad for an explanation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You essentially have it.

You will have 70 people in a list.  Once you have identified the position of the first teacher ($x$), the second teacher must be at position $x+7$, etc. up to the tenth teacher at position $x + 63$.  Thus, $x$ must be in the range $1 \leq x \leq 7$, for a total of $7$ possibilities.

Once you have identified the locations of the teachers, the remaining options are the orderings, so multiply $7$ by the numbers of permutations of students and teachers.  That gives your answer: $ 7 \times 10! \times 60!$.

Comment: Oh I see now. The index of the first teacher determining the indices of the other $9$, and there are $7$ possibilities..

Answer (score 1):

$T$ teachers means $T!$ ways to arrange them. $S$ students means $S!$ ways to arrange them. As for the $7$?

$T$ will represent one teacher. A number will represent some number of students.
$$T6T6T6T6T6T6T6T6T6T6$$
$$1T6T6T6T6T6T6T6T6T6T5$$
$$2T6T6T6T6T6T6T6T6T6T4$$
$$3T6T6T6T6T6T6T6T6T6T3$$
$$4T6T6T6T6T6T6T6T6T6T2$$
$$5T6T6T6T6T6T6T6T6T6T1$$
$$6T6T6T6T6T6T6T6T6T6T$$

That's there the $7$ comes from.

Between each teacher must be exactly $6$ students. There are $10$ teachers, making for $9$ between-teacher spaces occupied by $9\cdot6=54$ students.

This leaves $6$ students to stand on the sides of the $T6T6T6T6T6T6T6T6T6T$ arrangement. You start with all of them on one side for $1$ arrangement. Then you put one on the other side for another arrangement. You can do this $60-54=6$ times. Add those together to get $7$.

Comment: I'm not sure where you're getting $66$ from. But here's why it works with $60$. Listed above are the $7$ valid arrangements if you were to consider the teachers and students as identical within their group (i.e. you don't care about the order of the teachers or the students, you just care about the relationship between them). So for any particular valid arrangement, the teachers occupy $10$ of the spaces and the students occupy $60$. How many ways can you place the students in those $60$ slots? $60!$ ways.